# Background Process In Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows, compact-framework, background-process, windows-mobile-6.5

Hi I have a requirement in which i am having one application and a local database (eg sqlite)
application is in **windows mobile 6.5** , **.NET Compact Framework 3.5**
I need to create one **independent process** which keeps on running and takes data from local db of my application ,, do some processing and returns result to the application,,

independent process **must run** even my application get close.

please help..
thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx

Comment: it explains how to create threads.. dont you think it will be killed when entire app gets closed?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new process using the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Use IPC for communication, [possibly through P2P queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx) or a [MessageWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: where should i create process? if i create process in the same app then again closing that app will also force that process to be killed.? am i right?

Comment: No, a Process is a separate process, that's the point.  If your app shuts down, the other app continues to run.

Comment: To clarify: you need to create a second application. A process can launch another process or create and run threads. I f a process is quit, all threads that were created from the process are stopped. When you run two processes that access the same data, you have to find a  way for syncing the access. In example, two prcesses can not open the same sqlite db for exclusive reading and writing.